# Presence of ' in URL GET parameter identifier

Tags: php, url, get, query-string

If I have a URL of this kind:

`http://www.example.com/app.php?aa=10&bb=20`

```
<?php
echo $_GET["aa"]; //no problems
echo $_GET["bb"]; //no problems
?>
```

and

`http://www.example.com/app.php?'aa=10&bb=20`

What does the `'` in front of `aa` do? Is using `'` in GET variable identifiers illegal?

```
<?php
echo $_GET["'aa"]; //problem!
echo $_GET["bb"]; //no problems
// echo $_GET["aa"];  Also a problem
?>
```

Does that mean it doesn't even consider `'aa` as a GET parameter in the second case?

Thank you!

Comment: I can't reproduce your error. `$_GET["'aa"]` works fine for me.

Comment: From PHP-Website: A valid variable name starts with a letter or underscore, followed by any number of letters, numbers, or underscores. (http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php)

Comment: I believe that refers to a variable name, `$variable`, not a get query parameter found in the url.

Answer (score 0):

'a as a query string key isn't really good practice, however you can either url_encode it, or escape it.

As for putting it into a variable name, it would be an invalid character.
Variable names (and array keys) can only contain alphanumeric characters, and underscores.
Additionally, they shouldn't start with a number either.

In some circumstances, the apostrophe could be used as a way to inject code into your PHP script.

Overall, you should avoid putting apostrophes in querystring keys altogether :)

Comment: If its good practice then bad practice should work too. In This case its not working. Thats the question

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im by not good practice, I mean in some circumstances it can be used (code injection). However, in PHP, its an illegal character, appologies for not making that more unsterstood :)

Comment: It should work if you use `%27aa` in your PHP code (but it's ugly)